# Unix: how to count instances of each line across multiple files

Tags: sorting, unix, command, unique

I would be faced with hundreds or even thousands of files of the same name, but each in a subfolder with a different name. For simplicity of illustrating my question, I will use an example of only 3 different subfolders:

In `subfolder1/logfile.txt` I would have this content:

```
zebra
house
apple
car
```

In `subfolder2/logfile.txt` I would have this content:

```
apple
zebra
orange
sun
```

In `subfolder3/logfile.txt` I would have this content:

```
sun
love
zebra
hat
```

And I would like to get a single output file that would count in ALL the files with filename logfile.txt in ALL subdirectories(allways only one level deep) the occurrences of each row and return each unique row with the number of occurrences.

So the output I would want to get for this example would end up like this:

```
3 zebra
2 apple
2 sun
1 car
1 hat
1 house
1 love
1 orange
```

Could this be done in one single step/command line?

Would I first need to merge the contents of all the files into one and then apply a command that counts the unique rows and outputs to me in the way I described?

Or would I need to make a Python script(I could do that, but if a simple command gets me that why reinvent the wheel?)

In any case, how would I accomplish this?

Thank you very much!

EDIT: I have some extra requirement, hopefully it can all be put into a single command. In the output returned I would like to get as a second column all the subfolders where there was an ocurrence of that line. I am only interested in knowing about those that had 5 occurrences or less. So in the example I would want in the first line of the output something like:

`3 subfolder1,subfolder2,subfolder3 zebra`

`2 subfolder1,subfolder2 apple`

and so on, and for lines that would have more than 5 occurrences(there is none in this example)I would want to get nothing at all in that second column or even better, the phrase `many occurrences`

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can for example use `find` as follows:

```
$ find /your/path -name "logfile.txt" -exec cat {} \; | sort | uniq -c | sort -rn
      3 zebra
      2 sun
      2 apple
      1 orange
      1 love
      1 house
      1 hat
      1 car
```

This looks for all the `logfile.txt` files within the `/your/path` structure and `cat`s them. Then sorts the output and counts how many times each item appears. It finally sorts the output to have the biggest occurrence at the top.

---

### Update

According to your extended requirement, here you have a hint:

```
$ find . -name "logfile.txt" -exec grep -H "" {} \; | awk -F: '{a[$2]++; b[$2]=b[$2] OFS $1} END {for (i in a) print a[i], i, b[i]}' | sort -nr
3 zebra  ./t2/logfile.txt ./t1/logfile.txt ./t3/logfile.txt
2 sun  ./t2/logfile.txt ./t3/logfile.txt
2 apple  ./t2/logfile.txt ./t1/logfile.txt
1 orange  ./t2/logfile.txt
1 love  ./t3/logfile.txt
1 house  ./t1/logfile.txt
1 hat  ./t3/logfile.txt
1 car  ./t1/logfile.txt
```

`find` gets the files like before and then `grep -H "" {} \;` shows all the lines of the files, only that using the trick of `-H` we get the output with the name of the file on the left:

```
$ grep -H "" t2/a
t2/a:apple
t2/a:zebra
t2/a:orange
t2/a:sun
```

The `awk` command stores the times every word appears in the texts and also in which files it appears. Then it prints the results in the `END` block. Finally, `sort -rn` sorts the output.

Comment: You beat me to it! Lesson: `sort` and `uniq` are tools which are much more broadly useful than one might think at first.

Comment: @dodecafonico please update your question if you have further things you would like to get. If they are too broad to make a new question, don't doubt to ask a new one, as more people will see it and, hence, better solutions can appear.

Comment: Thank you very much fedorqui. I just edited my original question, adding my new requirement at the end, as you suggested. I hope I understood well what you meant. Cheers and thanks again :-)

Comment: @dodecafonico I did some updates on my answer. You can easily get your desired output from it...

Comment: million thanks. With all your explanation I will be able to work out on it to make it exactly how I want it, plus I will have learned about the way these powerful commands work :-)